# Select at least 1 checkbox in a loop of checkboxes group

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to get this thing work for a while but I guess I need to tweak the code from somewhere. I thought, someone here could better guide me instead of banging my head to my coding screen :)

here's the actual process:

```
<input type="hidden" name='oneSelectionChk_1'>
<input type="checkbox" name='awp_group_1' id='id1'>
<input type="checkbox" name='awp_group_1' id='id2'>
<input type="checkbox" name='awp_group_1' id='id3'>
<input type="checkbox" name='awp_group_1' id='id4'>


<input type="hidden" name='oneSelectionChk_2'>
<input type="checkbox" name='awp_group_2' id='id5'>
<input type="checkbox" name='awp_group_2' id='id6'>
<input type="checkbox" name='awp_group_2' id='id7'>
<input type="checkbox" name='awp_group_2' id='id8'>

<input type="hidden" name='oneSelectionChk_3'>
<input type="checkbox" name='awp_group_3' id='id9'>
<input type="checkbox" name='awp_group_3' id='id10'>
<input type="checkbox" name='awp_group_3' id='id11'>
<input type="checkbox" name='awp_group_3' id='id12'>
```

what I'm using for jQuery is:

```
var chkFields = $("input[name='oneSelectionChk']");
$.each(chkFields, function(i, field){
var groupID = field.id.split('_'); // Getting the ID of the group
var  chkGroupBoxes = $('input[name="awp_group_"'+groupID[1]);
   if(field.value==1)
   {
            //$.each(chkGroupBoxes, function(j, thisChkBox){
               //alert(thisChkBox.value + " #"+j);
               alert( $('input[name="awp_group_"'+groupID[1]).filter(':checked').length);
                 if($('input[name="awp_group_"'+groupID[1]+':checked').length > 0 )
                   {
                            //$.scrollTo( '#awp_container', 1200 );
                           alert($('input[name="awp_group_"'+groupID[1]+':checked').length+" Selected ");
                           //alert( "Class AlertMsgText Should be removed Now");
                           $("#selectInstruction_"+groupID[1]).removeClass("AlertMsgText");
                         //return
                   }
                   else
                   {
                      alert($('input[name="awp_group_"'+groupID[1]+':checked').length+" Still not selected ");
                     //alert("Please select atleat 1 from Option #"+groupID[1]);
                     $("#selectInstruction_"+groupID[1]).addClass("AlertMsgText");
                     $.scrollTo( '#awp_container', 1200 );
                    //return;
                 }
          //});
      }
    });
```

This code always giving me 0 length of checkboxes, I'm not sure if I need to loop through again for each checkbox or this might work?

Any quick help should be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var chkFields = $('input[name^="oneSelectionChk"]');
$.each(chkFields, function (i, field) {
    var groupID = field.name.replace('oneSelectionChk_', '')
    var chkGroupBoxes = $('input[name="awp_group_' + groupID + '"]');

    if (chkGroupBoxes.filter(':checked').length == 0) {
        alert('please select at least one checkbox under: ' + field.name)
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/msfka/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no element with `name` attribute of `oneSelectionChk` in your markup, the hidden inputs have `name` attributes that start with `oneSelectionChk`, you have to use `attribute starts with` selector.

In case that elements are siblings you can select the target elements using `.nextUntil()` method:

```
var $hidden = $('input[type=hidden]').filter('[name^=oneSelectionChk]');

$hidden.each(function(){
   var $chekboxes = $(this).nextUntil('input[type=hidden]'),
       $checked = $checkboxes.filter(':checked'),
       $unchecked = $chekboxes.not($checked); 
});
```

Using `name` attributes:

```
var $hidden = $('input[type=hidden]').filter('[name^=oneSelectionChk]'),
    $checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');

$hidden.each(function() {
   var n = this.name.split('_')[1];
   var $grp = $checkboxes.filter('[name="awp_group_'+ n +'"]');
   // ..
});
```

Comment: Thanks both of you for your contribution, I tried the later method and figured out how dump I was as I'm accessing by name oneSelectionChk  where only id is different for each group and I keep the name same

    <input type="text" id="oneSelectionChk_{$group.id_group}" name="oneSelectionChk" value="{$group.one_selection_required}" />


now changed to

    <input type="text" id="oneSelectionChk_{$group.id_group}" name="oneSelectionChk_{$group.id_group}" value="{$group.one_selection_required}" />

and everything working like a charm. Thanks for saving my time :)